# FetchRequest with NSPredicate does not update on new entries

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am experimenting with SwiftUI and CoreData.
In a ListView I show all Entries with a given Predicate via a `FetchRequest`:

```
struct MyList: View {
    var task: Task

    @FetchRequest
    var events: FetchedResults<Event>

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    var viewContext

    init(task: Task) {
        self.task = task
        self._events = FetchRequest(entity: Event.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Event.timestamp, ascending: true)],
                                    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Event.task), task.id.uuidString), animation: .default)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            EditButton()
            List {
                ForEach(self.events, id: \.self) { event in
                    Text("\(event.someProperty)")
                }
            }.onDelete { indices in
                self.events.delete(at: indices, from: self.viewContext)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(
             trailing: Button(
                 action: {
                     withAnimation {
                         Event.create(for: self.task, in: self.viewContext)
                     }
                 }
              ) {
                  Image(systemName: "plus")
              }
        )
    }
}

extension Event {
    static func create(for task: Task, in managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext){
        let newEvent = self.init(context: managedObjectContext)
        newEvent.task = task.id
        newEvent.timestamp = Date()

        do {
            try  managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }   
}

extension Collection where Element == Event, Index == Int {
    func delete(at indices: IndexSet, from managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        indices.forEach { managedObjectContext.delete(self[$0]) }       

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works if fine. If I delete a an entry it gets automatically dismissed from the list.

But if I add an entry its only added to the list after an app restart. If I remove the `NSPredicate` new entries are shown immediately. Is this a bug or am I missing something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you do in `Event.create`?

Comment: I added the Extension Code for `Event`

Comment: Presumably Task.id is a UUID.  You set newEvent.task = task.id, but your predicate specifies task == task.id.uuidString.  My guess is that during the fetch, CoreData successfully bridges UUID to its string equivalent, but the in memory processing by the context doesn’t.  Does it work any better if you use task == task.id as the predicate?

Comment: pbasdf you nailed it. Comparing the UUIDs just makes more sense. I was confused with the `Argument type 'UUID' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'` Error. But with a cast to CVarArg everything works. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has [pbasdf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3985749/pbasdf) pointed out the problem is indeed with the UUID compare in the `NSPredicate`. After comparing the UUIDs instead of the Strings everything works as expected.

Comparing the UUID to a given String works fetching the initial data. Probably its been handled correctly in the database but not for "in memory" processing. e.g.

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Event.task), task.id.uuidString)
```

works for deletion operation but not for insertions of new entries.

To resolve this issue the predicate should look like this

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Event.task), task.id as CVarArg)
```

see also:
https://jisyed.github.io/blog/2018/using-uuids-in-predicates-to-fetch-core-data-entities/

Comment: after a year i found my problem with this great answer thank thank you thank you a lot of thank you so much i am really happy thank you